# Javascript formdata object doesn't send any key, pair value over to the django framework

Tags: javascript, django

Django framework isn't able to print the post data from the XMLHttpRequest
I'm writing vanilla javascript by the way and not jquery,
Please don't write a jquery answer .
Thanks In Advance.

## BELOW IS MY HTML CODE

```
<form action="{% url 'feed:update_comment' comment.id %}" 
method="POST" onsubmit="UpdateComment(event)" 
class="comment-update-form">{% csrf_token %}

<div class="close-comment-box"onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add('hide')">
<span>&times;</span>
</div>

<textarea name="body" id="post_body">{{comment.text}}</textarea>

<div class="btn-div">
<button type="submit" class="button">Update</button>
</div>
</form>
```

## BELOW IS MY VANILLA JAVASCRIPT

```
    function UpdateComment(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    let comment_field_to_update = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.comment-text-div').querySelector('.feed_text_element')
    const data = new FormData(event.target);
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload = (response)=>{
        console.log(response)
    }
    xhttp.open("POST",event.target.getAttribute("action","action"),true)
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",'application/x-www-formurlencoded')
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken',csrftoken)
    xhttp.send(data)
}
```

## BELOW IS MY PYTHON DJANGO CODE

```py
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    @login_required
    def updateComment(request,id):
        if request.method == "POST":
        response = {}
        try:
            comment = Comment.objects.get(id=id)
            if comment.author == request.user:
                comment.text = request.POST['body']
                comment.save
                response['200'] = comment.text
                return JsonResponse(response)
            else:
                response['400'] = 'You Can"t Edit This Comment'
                return JsonResponse(response)
        except Comment.DoesNotExist:
            response['404'] = 'Comment Not Found'
            return JsonResponse(response)
```

## BELOW IS THE ERROR I'M GETTING FROM DJANGO

```
    System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
    August 29, 2020 - 17:23:54
    Django version 2.2.14, using settings 'jumbo.settings'
    Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
    Internal Server Error: /update_comment&comment_identifier=/9/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 78, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)`enter code here`
    KeyError: 'body'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
         response = get_response(request)
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/handlerenter code heres/base.py", line 115, 
       in _get_response
         response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
         response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in 
         _wrapped_view
         return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
       File "/media/freduah/7A1809E218099E6F/Jumbo Media/jumbo/feed/views.py", line 235, in
          updateComment
          comment.text = request.POST['body']
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 80, in __getitem__
          raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
          django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'body'
          [29/Aug/2020 17:23:55] "POST /update_comment&comment_identifier=/9/ HTTP/1.1" 500 81293
```

It's works fine when i switch to jquery but i don't want to use any library in my code.
If you could please help with vanilla javascript solutions only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormData` sets the content type to `multipart/form-data` automatically,  not `x-www-formurlencoded`.

Remove the `setRequestHeader()` accordingly and treat it as multipart server side

Comment: Note you may want to use the more modern `fetch()` api rather than XMLHttpRequest